# Struct passing self causes: self subtype of @lvaue error

Tags: swift

Best way I can describe the situation is just to show an example:

```
struct One {
  func setup(inout t:Two) {
    // inout is important to not copy the struct in
  } 
}

struct Two {
  func getOne() -> One {
    var o = One()
    o.setup(&self) // Two is not subtype of '@lvalue $T5'
    return o
  }
}
```

Why is this happening and how can I get past it?

Comment: try add `mutating` to `getOne`, otherwise you can't modify `self`

Comment: @JackWu I get the same error, but this time on t.

Comment: @BryanChen That worked! Not sure why as I don't mutate Two's self in One.

Comment: Great catch with `mutating`. It makes sense because `inout` is used to specify that you **intend** to alter the parameter. In this use case though, at least one of these `structs` should really be implemented as `classes` instead of (essentially) "abusing" `inout` to provide the pass-by-reference functionality

Answer (score 1):

you need to add `mutating` keyword to the method. otherwise method in struct are default to immutable, which means you cannot modify `self` in the method. and pass `self` to another method takes `inout` keyword implicitly saying you are going to modify it.

```
struct Two {
  mutating func getOne() -> One {
    var o = One()
    o.setup(&self) // Two is not subtype of '@lvalue $T5'
    return o
  }
}
```